# Scroll snapping does not work with the following code. How do I fix it? (I am using newest version of chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, scroll

I am trying to figure out why my scroll snap code isn't working. Can you please help fix my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <h3>header 1</h3>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h3>header 2</h3>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

The following is the CSS code:

```
body {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-padding-top: 15vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

section{
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `container` for the `sections`. I this case I took `<main>` as the `container`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <h3>header 1</h3>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>header 2</h3>
  </section>
</main>
```

Check it in action on Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/LYbxazG?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know if there is a way to scroll with mouse wheel and not the scroll bar on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the overflow is happening on `html` element instead of `body` which you are considering as your `scrol-snap` container.

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-padding-top: 15vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

section{
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h3>header 1</h3>
</section>
<section>
  <h3>header 2</h3>
</section>
```